# How to transform factor variable to make it statistically significant for logistical regression modeling in r?

Tags: r

i am trying to predict whether the teams playing soccer match will win or lose. there is a factor variable seasons, which is not coming out to be statistically significant. how can i transform that variable in a way that it becomes significant for my model.

Comment: There's no R question here. This seems like a stats question.

Comment: hmmmm transforming it in a way that makes it sound significant sounds extremely weird.. if there's no relationship how can you even force it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't.

Longer answer: Searching for some transformation that makes things significant, just to make it significant, is not recommended. It is one type of p-hacking. You don't say what your variable "seasons" means, but I'm guessing it is either something such as: Fall, Winter, Spring, Summer or else the year in which the match was played.  Probably the former, since year is not really nominal (factor).

Whether there is anything to do to improve your model depends on your actual research question, but the most likely answer is that either:

- Your sample size is too small for an effect like the one you found to be significant or
- Your notion that season is related to result of a soccer match is simply incorrect.